# Expand container inside column to fit column height in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Why does the green container expand over the blue column when I set `height: 100%` or `h-100`?

How can I make it to just fit the remaining height of the column?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" style="background-color: black">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: red">
      <p>Some</p>
      <p>More</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: blue">
      <h3>Content I want to keep</h2>
      <section class="d-flex h-100" style="background-color: green">
        <button class="btn btn-danger m-auto">Centered Button</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to overlay the green block into the blue block.

It can't set height because there is text ( two ) in between two blocks.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" style="background-color: black">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: red">
      <p>Some</p>
      <p>More</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: blue">
      <section class="d-flex h-100" style="background-color: green">
        <button class="btn btn-danger m-auto">Centered Button</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to have the `Two` text and the container should expand the remainder of the height of the column.

I got it working by setting the parent container box model to flex with vertical direction, but I wonder if there's another way